# How to add more Items in Scrollview in Android?

Tags: android, scrollview

My android page has 10 EditText and 10 TextView. but there is no space in my screen in the Graphical Layout. i just added 5 only. im using Scroll layout. how to add additional 5  items in the screen without reducing the items height. Is there any coding here.?

Comment: comment some views already added. Then the bottom view will comes to top and you can add more view and also you can see that.

Answer (score 16):

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <TextView/>..
    ....
     ..
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can add multiple items inside a LinearLayout. Since ScrollView is scrollable it won't affect the dimensions of the Views inside. You can add as many views as you need without worrying about screen size or View size..

Answer (score 5):

You should add a `LinearLayout` as the only child inside your `ScrollView`. Then get a reference to that `LinearLayout` :

```
mLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
```

and then add `Views` dynamically from code using :

```
EditText et=new EditText(...);
//....
mLayout.addView(et);
```

Answer (score 4):

A `ScrollView` can have only one direct child, so you need to put all the other Views in a `Layout`, such as `LinearLayout` and put that layout in `ScrollView`

Make your `ScrollView`'s height as `match_parent` and the inner `LinearLayout`'s height as `wrap_content`. The `LinearLayout` will stretch according to the number of children inside it and if the height exceeds the height of the `ScrollView`, the overflow can be seen by scrolling. If the `ScrollView` and inner Layout both have same height or if `ScrollView` have larger height than inner Layout, the scrolling won't happen for obvious reason.